# Decreasing sequence of set where $\mu(A_n)=\infty$ and $\mu(\cap A_n) <\infty$

Tags: measure-theory

I am looking at some old problems to prepare for the exam.

I came across this one:
Find a decreasing sequence $A_n \supseteq A_{n+1}$ where $\mu(A_n)=\infty$ and $\mu(\cap A_n) <\infty$

I tried:
$A_n=[n,\infty)$ which makes it decreasing for $n \rightarrow\infty$. And also $\mu(A_n)=\infty$. But it doesn't give the intersection

I have run out of ideas, any hint would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sequence $(A_n)$ is in fact increasing since $A_n \subseteq A_{n+1}$.

Take $A_n := [n;+\infty[$ instead. One has $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n= \emptyset$, this has measure $0$.

Comment: Was a stupid typo with the minus - fixed it. I can see you are right with the emptyset, so it was the interpretation I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel Glad I could help. Please accept the answer if you like it. ;)

Comment: Done :) and thanks